# Hiding UITableView separator behind the contentView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, separator

I made a grouped UITableView in iPhone OS 3.0 that looked like the left image. The result is the right image in OS 3.1.

[image]

The imageView is under the separators.

I've tried to put the content view in front. The separatorStyle propriety seems ignored when the tableView is in grouped style (to draw the separator myself). Changing the separator color gives strings results.

Thanks for your help!

Edit: This is the code with no change made :

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [[metro.arretDirection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];

NSString* name;
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    name = @"Begining";
}
else if (indexPath.row + 1 == [metro.arretDirection count]) {
    name = @"End";
}
else {
    if ([[[metro.arretDirection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] lines] count]== 1) name = @"Little";
    else name = @"Big";
}

UIImage* metroImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%@.png", metro.metroNumber, name]]];
cell.imageView.image = metroImage;
[metroImage release];

return cell;
```

Comment: This is curious.  Can you please post the relevant code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was actually quite simple, simply add an `UIImageView` in the cell an place it properly instead of using the built in imageView.

Answer (score 1):

On the cell try setting [clipsToBounds](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds) to NO. eg `cell.clipsToBounds = NO;`

Comment: It's possible that the size of the imageView was shrunk by 2 pixels in 3.1 so write the frame of the imageView to the log and see what it says. Also see what the `contentMode` of the imageView is in 3.0 and how it compares with 3.1, also try the `clipsToBounds` property of the imageView. And possibly even the imageView's layer's `masksToBounds` property (though this should already be set to no).