# Inserting image in UITableView cell issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

sorry for the silly question, but I'm still in the process of learning Objective-C and iPhone programming.

I'm trying to insert an icon to the left of a UITableView cell. This is from the method  `(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` :

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"icon3" ofType:@"png"];
UIImage *icon = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
cell.imageView.image = icon;
```

My icon (30w x 44h) MUST be as high as the cell, while **at the moment it remains a little space** (maybe 1 pixel) **above it and below**. I tried to change the dimensions of the image with no success and I tried to reduce the height of the cell (with no effect) with `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`.

What can I do?

Eventually I should insert a little space on the left too, but this is secondary.

Thanks very much.

[image: This is the screenshot: check that white pixel above the yellow icon]

[UPDATE] no problem when the UITableView is not "grouped"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the height of the row for the cell.imageView to be resized.

implement the following method and return the height of your image.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Try also removing the contentMode setting in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method.  You can replace all your code with one line as below:

```
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon3.png"];
```

Comment: No, I tried this solution before posting and it doesn't work.

Comment: I use the code in my app and it works just fine.  I dont use anything special, just a simple default style cell.  my image is 72px high and return a row height of 80,  to setup my cell, i set the text, set the imageView.image property and thats it, nothing else.

Comment: do you have a screen shot of how its displaying in your app?  are you using cell seperator lines? is it a grouped table or standard flat table?

Comment: The grouped table style defaults to the "Single Line Etched" seperator style.  Thats why you are seeing the white line, as the seperator has a white highlight to simulate the etched look.  Try changing the seperator to "Single Line"  that should get rid of your gaps.

Comment: Oh, wow, thanks, it works. A rapid question, if you have the time: is there any way to get rid of a part of the separator? My goal is to show a continuous line, just like in the image at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1430404/hiding-uitableview-separator-behind-the-contentview (maybe I should add the image in a subview, the use the solution by Syed)...

Comment: No that I know of, it sounds like the only option would be to add a UIImageView to the cell and bring it to the front.

Comment: Ok, I did this way. To re-position the text (it flows under the UIImageView), at the moment I use the dirty trick to add extra spaces to the strings.

Answer (score 2):

Based on code from CanadaDev [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/23582-cell-imageview-image-image-not-showing-up.html#post104563):

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5,20,20)]; // set the location and size of your imageview here.
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]; // set the image for the imageview
imageView.highlightedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageHighlighted.png"]; // if you need it, this will allow you to create an image used when the cell is highlighted. For example, a white copy of your image to match the white text.
[cell addSubview:imageView];
```

and then for text:

```
UILabel *price=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,60, 180,12)];
price.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"price %@",temp];
price.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
[price setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"American Typewriter" size:12]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:price];
[price release];
```

Comment: This has 2 drawbacks: it design my image 20x20 (ok, I imagine we can change it), but the text in the cell is covered by the icon.

Comment: for text you have to draw a frame too .

Comment: I don't know how to do it: could you please post a link to a resource to study?

Comment: check my updated code. you have to play with values of x to adjust it.

Comment: A further question (don't answer if you have no time): it is actually possible to set a cell background? I could use a round icon (not rectangular) and under the cell, with same x and width of the icon, I could set a background.

Comment: UIImage *cellBack = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell-1.png"];
cell.backgroundView =[[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:cellBack] autorelease];

Answer (score 0):

Try to adjust the size of `cell.imageView`.

```
cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0) //fill in appropriate location and size for the zeros
```

Comment: Mmm..., could you tell me some more?

Comment: `cell.imageView.bounds = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)` (fill in appropriate location and size for the zeros).

Comment: I tried it, but it always shows a little space (1 pixel) above: I tried to use a negative number for the y, but with no effect.